# Oracle - Why I can't exclude rows where length(listagg(somecolumn)) > xxx

Tags: sql, oracle, string-length, listagg

I just can't seem to work this one out :(

I run a query that returns some results but in those results I need to filter out where this customer does not have freetext notes that are greater than 240 characters

Unfortunately the way the Data is stored is notes are split up across multiple rows as such:

```
NOTE_NUMBER    LINE_NUMBER    NOTE_TEXT
123            1              ABC
123            2              DEFGHIJ
456            1              ABCDEE
```

etc
NOTE_NUMBER is the Primary Key back to another table
I already worked out how to return one result row per NOTE_NUMBER

```
SELECT A.NOTE_NUMBER, LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT)
FROM TABLE TABLE 1 A
JOIN TABLE 2 B ON A.NOTE_NUMBER = B.NOTE_NUMBER
GROUP BY A.NOTE_NUMBER
```

This returns me:

```
123 ABCDEFGHIJ
456 ABCDEE
```

fantastic! But now say I only want to to return rows where the LENGTH(LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT)) < 7 heres where I am stumped.

I already saw this works to change my query to:

```
SELECT A.NOTE_NUMBER, LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT), LENGTH(LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT))
FROM TABLE TABLE 1 A
JOIN TABLE 2 B ON A.NOTE_NUMBER = B.NOTE_NUMBER
GROUP BY A.NOTE_NUMBER
```

now gives me:

```
123 ABCDEFGHIJ 11
456 ABCDEE 7
```

however if I want to put a where clause in so now:

```
SELECT A.NOTE_NUMBER, LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT), LENGTH(LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT))
FROM TABLE TABLE 1 A
JOIN TABLE 2 B ON A.NOTE_NUMBER = B.NOTE_NUMBER
WHERE LENGTH(LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT)) < 7
GROUP BY A.NOTE_NUMBER
```

I get an error

```
ORA-00934 group function is not allowed here
```

so then my searching brought me using CASE:

```
SELECT A.NOTE_NUMBER, CASE WHEN LENGTH(LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT)) < 7 THEN LISTAGG(NOTE_TEXT) END
FROM TABLE TABLE 1 A
JOIN TABLE 2 B ON A.NOTE_NUMBER = B.NOTE_NUMBER
GROUP BY A.NOTE_NUMBER
```

however this still returns 2 rows

```
123 NULL
456 ABCDEE
```

this will be no good to me when I try to do a not exists where length of note is > 7 characters because both rows will still return so the NOTE_NUMBER key will still match back to the other table

I tried to find out how can I exclude rows if that CASE is NULL and can't figure that out either!

All I need is this query to have returned is this:

```
456 ABCDEE
```

Please help me! Much Appreciated!

Comment: An order of evaluation in general `SELECT` statement is: `from`, `join`, `where` (generally merged into `from/join`, i.e. applied at the same time as these operations), `group by`, `having`, `select` list items, `distinct` if present, `order by`. This is a basic SQL syntax. So it becomes clear that `listagg` result is not available yet in the context of `where` clause, because it is an aggregation.

Comment: The error message is also [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90202/e900.htm#1656) and shows this additional info in SQL\*Plus (or SQL Developer when you run script through F5). **ORA-00934**.
**Cause**: *One of the group functions, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, was used in a `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clause.*
**Action**: *Remove the group function from the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clause. The desired result may be achieved by including the function in a subquery or `HAVING` clause.*

Answer (score 4):

One option is to put your query in a CTE or subquery (I don't repeat that query here because the other answer shows it).

Another option is to use `HAVING` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

The reason why your attempt failed is that you can't use an aggregate function like `LISTAGG` in the `WHERE` clause.

Using `HAVING`, you can use it!

```
SELECT 
  t1.NOTE_NUMBER, 
  LISTAGG(t1.NOTE_TEXT) AS wholeText, 
  LENGTH(LISTAGG(t1.NOTE_TEXT)) AS wholeLength
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.NOTE_NUMBER = t2.NOTE_NUMBER
GROUP BY t1.NOTE_NUMBER
  HAVING LENGTH(LISTAGG(t1.NOTE_TEXT)) < 7;
```

Try out both options on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Un7whM69)

Comment: Thankyou! Knew it was going to be a simple one! yes used  HAVING LENGTH(LISTAGG(t1.NOTE_TEXT)) < 7; is what I needed thanks!

Comment: @David You're welcome, I'm glad your problem is solved. Could you please read this article, also for future questions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's fairly simple - use query (that works) as a *source* (either as CTE or subquery) for another `select` statement which just uses what you've already collected:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT a.note_number,
                LISTAGG (note_text) note_text,
                LENGTH (LISTAGG (note_text)) note_len
           FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.note_number = b.note_number
       GROUP BY a.note_number)
SELECT *
  FROM temp
 WHERE note_len < 7
```